# Set a different variable depending on bool expression in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart we might want to set a variable to some fixed value, but which variable we set may depend on some bool expression. For example

```
String value = 'Hello World!';
bool sendToFirst = false;

String first = '';
String second = '';

if (sendToFirst){
  first = value;
else {
  second = value;
}
```

This block would do what you want, but is there a more concise way of doing this? Something like

```
(sendToFirst ? first : second) = value;
```

But of course this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to simplify if statements: **Ternary expressions**.
Following your example you have to code:

```
sendToFirst ? first = value : second = value
```

In the end you are just replacing the keywords with syntactic sugar, where the `?` replaces the "if bool is true"-part, followed by a condition that should be executed (the body of the condition) and the colon `:` for the else-part, again, followed by a body.

FYI: You can mark value final, if you are not planning to re-asign a new value to it.